# Is a single HIPAA waiver enough for teenager's parent?

Tags: united-states, medical, teenager

I see [articles](https://raisingteenstoday.com/legal-documents-you-need-when-your-child-turns-18/) and [site](https://mamabearlegalforms.com/youngadult) and need to protect for out of state (parents in one of the USA state, and teenager going to other USA state).

On HIPAA, I am confused if we should get it signed but what doctor or facility name should I put, we will not know until emergency (hopefully not to my kid nor to any one's kid) arise.

Is there a acceptable version of HIPAA form that is blanket permission to parents?

Comment: It feels like there are some words or context missing here. Such as "need to protect for out of state" ???

Comment: @ohwilleke basically i am looking for having a single HIPPA authorization/ waiver form that our kid can sign and be valid for any doctor/hospital and Facility.